# Preview PDF content in IE using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf, preview

I have a functionality in my Spring Boot-AngularJS project where I have to show the preview of the PDF file selected by the user using the  element.

I have got that to work in Chrome and Firefox, but IE doesn't seem to show the preview.

Any help is appreciated. Below is my code:

**In controller:**

```
        previewSelectedFile = function() {
            file = new Blob([$scope.documentTemplate.templateFileModel], {
                type : 'application/pdf'
            });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        };
```

**In HTML:**

*File Selection:*

```
<input type="file" id="templateFile" ng-model="documentTemplate.templateFileModel" file-model="documentTemplate.templateFileModel" ng-change="previewSelectedFile()" accept="application/pdf" name="templateFile">
```

*File Preview:*

```
<object data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></object>
```